# UIImage MKOverlay Appears on Simulator but not Device

Tags: ios, uiimage, mapkit, mkoverlay

So I have put together a map-based application which works just fine in the simulator. Everything, including the overlay, is shown. However, when I loaded the app onto my iPad, the overlay image does not show.

The user's location shows (real not simulated) and the proper mapRect shows. The overlay is set to `replaceMapContent` and it does - there is an area with just gridlines (no Apple Maps features) though the rest of the world does. The image is selected in the `MKOverlayRender` class and the image name is exactly correct. It is a mid-size image (768 × 1024 pixels - 268 KB)

Any idea how to display the `UIImage` on the device? I can show any code needed, just ask.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Should I/Do I need to turn the overlay into `MKTileOverlay` or anything like that?

**ADDITION** - The Code

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *location;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property(nonatomic) MKCoordinateRegion region;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect boundingMapRect;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D bjorkOverlayCenterPoint;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) MKMapRect bjorkOverlayBoundingMapRect;




@property (nonatomic, strong) MKOverlayRenderer *mapOverlay;

- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)image;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "OverlayObject.h"
#import "OverlayRender.h"

@interface ViewController () <MKMapViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    _mapView.delegate = self;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(    45.023530, -87.137282);
    MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoord);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(   45.046828, -87.127900);
    MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoord);
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);

    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapRect animated:YES];


    OverlayObject *mapOverlay = [[OverlayObject alloc] init];
    mapOverlay.canReplaceMapContent = YES;
    [_mapView addOverlay:mapOverlay];
}


- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

    OverlayRender *mapOverlay = [[OverlayRender alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    return mapOverlay;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

OverlayObject.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface OverlayObject : NSObject <MKOverlay>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D bjorkOverlayCenterPoint;

@property (nonatomic) MKMapRect bjorkOverlayBoundingMapRect;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL canReplaceMapContent;

@end
```

OverlayObject.m

```
#import "OverlayObject.h"

@implementation OverlayObject

@synthesize coordinate, bjorkOverlayCenterPoint, bjorkOverlayBoundingMapRect;

-(MKMapRect)boundingMapRect{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D lowerLeftCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(  45.025030 ,-87.144482);
    MKMapPoint lowerLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(lowerLeftCoord);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D upperRightCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake( 45.046528, -87.122400);
    MKMapPoint upperRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(upperRightCoord);
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake(lowerLeft.x, upperRight.y, upperRight.x - lowerLeft.x, lowerLeft.y - upperRight.y);

    return mapRect;
}


- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)bjorkOverlayCenterPoint
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = {
        45.035728,-87.1356855
    };

    return coord1;
}

@end
```

ObjectRender.h

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface OverlayRender : MKOverlayRenderer

@end
```

ObjectRender.m

```
#import "OverlayRender.h"

@implementation OverlayRender

- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"OverlayDraft.png"];


    MKMapRect theMapRect = [self.overlay boundingMapRect];
    CGRect theRect = [self rectForMapRect:theMapRect];

    UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
    [image drawInRect:theRect blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();



}


@end
```

Ok that is all the code. Any ideas or suggestion or hypotheses for displaying the image on the device would be so appreciate.

Comment: I have been playing around with the UIImage location a bit and I believe that is part of the problem. The image is saved in the "Images.xcassets" folder and I thought I was calling it out of there. However I deleted the image (moved it all to trash) and I changed the image name with changing what I was calling in the code and the image was still overlaid on the map perfectly. Of course, I checked and there is no image or anything in Interface Builder (just the map view). Any idea how that is possible?

Comment: Ok, by dragging the image from finder into it's own location in the supporting files folder, I got it to display on the device. I still do not understand why I could not call it out of Images.xcassets folder though